# onDisconnect() fails with permission error on unauth()

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble getting Firebase authentication to work with an anonymous user. I'm building a chat app using Firechat.js, which attaches a onDisconnect() handler to set the user "offline".

However, it seems when I call firebase.unauth() it logs the user out before the onDisconnect()  has a chance to set the user "offline", so it fails with a permission error (this is my theory).

The log shows exactly how everything transpires as I login and then logout:

```
 app.js: using username: John Smith  <<logged in
 app.js: calling firebase.unauth()   <<logged out
 firechat.js: Firechat Warning: Firechat requires an authenticated Firebase reference. Pass an authenticated reference before loading.
 app.js: using username: Anonymous3aa-437b  <<after logout, reauthenticate as anonymous
 firebase.js: FIREBASE WARNING: set at /chat/user-names-online/john smith/-KE9LcpieTwxj_A4sBHz failed: permission_denied
```

As you see the user is anonymous before Firechat has a chance to set the previous user offline. [Here is the onDisconnect() bit in firechat.js](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/src/js/firechat.js#L164)

Here's my app code:

```
var $firebase = new Firebase(...);
var $firechat = new Firechat(...);

$firebase.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {

     var username = authData[authData.provider].displayName;
     var anonusername = "Anonymous" + authData.uid.substr(10, 8);

     console.log('using username: ' + username || anonusername);

     //set firechat user and resume chatting session (user becomes "online")
     $firechat.setUser(authData.uid, username || anonusername, function() {
        $firechat.resumeSession();
     });

  } else {
     //if not logged in, authenticate anonymously 
     $firebase.authAnonymously(function(error) {
        if (error) {
           console.log(error);
        }
     });
  }
});
```

Here's the security rule for user-names-online:

```
 "user-names-online": {
      // A mapping of active, online lowercase usernames to sessions and user ids.
      ".read": true,
      "$username": {
        "$sessionId": {
          ".write": "(auth != null) && (!data.exists() || !newData.exists() || data.child('id').val() === auth.uid || auth.provider === 'anonymous')",
          "id": {
            ".validate": "(newData.val() === auth.uid)"
          },
          "name": {
            ".validate": "(newData.isString())"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

It seems firechat is built for this scenario, so why is it failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing a few things:

- calling `unauth()` drop the authentication session for the user.

  - It does not disconnect the user.
  - It *does* cancel any listeners for location that require authentication.
- the code you attach to `onDisconnect()` runs on the Firebase servers, once they detect that the client has disconnected.

  - If the `onDisconnect()` handler removes the user from some sort of presence system, other clients can see that the user disappears.
  - the client that disconnected cannot immediately see the result of its own disconnect, because it has already disconnected.
  - if a client wants to know when it has disconnected, monitor the `.info/connected` value.